# Instruction operands must be the same size when storing a char to an assembly register

Tags: assembly, x86, char, masm

I am trying to store a char like "B" on an assembly register like so:

```
mov edx, col
```

where `col` is a global defined as "B". However, upon compiling this, it returns the following error: `instruction operands must be the same size A2022`

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: please provide a complete example including what assembler (tool) you are using and the command line.

Comment: You mean *load*, into a register, I think?  A byte load into a dword register should be done with `movzx edx, byte ptr [col]`.

Comment: @old_timer: Numbered error codes like `A2022` are I think unique to MASM.  But yes, the question *should* have identified that, and provided a [mcve] including the definition like `col db "B"` instead of `col dd "B"` or something that you'd need for this 32-bit load to assemble without an override.